# Get all category members and go over subcategories in MediaWiki API

Tags: mediawiki-api

I need the list of pages under particular category and it's subcategories.
I know how to get query from Wikipedia.

A simple query to get Pages of a category as mentioned [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aCategorymembers) is to define the parameters of query as:

```
action = query
list = categorymembers
cmtitle = Category:Physics
```

This gives the normal output which contains subcategories and pages under the physics category. I know I can go step by step in categories under by under to get all the pages under Mother category. But is it a way to get all pages by one query request?

Comment: No. MediaWiki's category system allows infinite levels of nested categories and even cycles in them. In such situation, recursive category traversal becomes a complex problem dependent on each particular use case, so MediaWiki does not implement this. You are given the means to do it yourself, however.